# SQL If Value Exists then return that otherwise return whole table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Note: This is an over simplified version of what I am trying to do.

Let's say I have a table called USERS that has FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME. Contents are:

```
JOHN   SMITH
DAVID  BECKHAM
ELON   MUSK
```

I want to query this table so that if a value exists it just returns that value, otherwise it returns the whole table. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM USERS
WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'JOHN'
```

This would return

```
JOHN   SMITH
```

However if the query was

```
SELECT *
FROM USERS
WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'JANE'
```

Then the return would be

```
JOHN   SMITH
DAVID  BECKHAM
ELON   MUSK
```

This is being done in SQL Server but there is potential for Oracle too in case it is different.

Comment: Can't be done efficiently in a single statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select a row when the name matches or there is no match for that name in the table. Translated almost word by word into SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE firstname = 'JOHN'
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = 'JOHN');
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample which might work in Oracle or SQL-server, if your RDBMS support `CTE`

We can try to use `UNION ALL` and `NOT EXISTS` to make it.

Filter `FIRSTNAME` in `CTE` if the first result exists value which means you filter a `FIRSTNAME` then you will only get the record (because `NOT EXISTS` will not let the second result set work).

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM USERS
  WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'JANE'
)
SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
FROM CTE 
UNION ALL
SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
FROM USERS 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM CTE
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=28a4b5ecb5c13f34ab99b97e64c4f51c)

Comment: Pretty efficient (as long as firstname is indexed.)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, I will test it more in the code i have but this is definitely a viable option.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this - perhaps with slight variations in syntax between the SQL dialects. Find the occurrence of `'John'` in the `order by` clause of the analytic function in the subquery - that's where you should have your bind variable instead.

```
select first_name, last_name
from   (
         select first_name, last_name,
                dense_rank() over (order by case first_name
                                     when 'John' then 1 end) as rn
         from   users
       )
where  rn = 1
;
```

How this works: The `case` expression assigns the value 1 when the first name is **John** (or whatever the input is), and `null` otherwise. So, either some rows are assigned 1 and others `null`, or else all rows are assigned `null`. The `dense_rank` analytic function will assign 1 to the rows with a non-null value and 2 to the rows assigned `null`, **or else** it will assign 1 to **all** rows, if **all** rows are assigned `null` in the `case` expression. Then the outer query selects only the rows where the dense rank is 1; these are all the "John" rows, if there are any, but otherwise it selects **all** rows.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an ordering column using `TOP (1) WITH TIES`

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  FIRSTNAME,
  LASTNAME
FROM (
    SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, 1 AS Ordering
    FROM USERS
    WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'JANE'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, 2
    FROM USERS
) u
ORDER BY Ordering;
```